# Fixing a pedestrian traffic light sequence pattern in a cycle using millis and without delay

Tags: esp8266, interrupt, time, millis

I was emulating the pedestrian traffic light cyclic pattern (red, green, green flashing) in the next Arduino code. But when I run this code with my ESP8266 Wemos D1 mini controller, it appears the pattern (red, red and (green flashing) at the same time, green). I do not know why this strange pattern appeared and I was trying to fix it, but I did not get anything. How to fix this code to replicate the (red, green, green flashing) sequence pattern?

```
// Define pin assignments
const int redLED = D1;
const int greenLED = D2;
const int pedestrianButton = D3;
const int potentiometer = A0;

// Define variables
unsigned long lastStateChangeTime = 0;
unsigned long greenFlashingDuration = 3000; // 3 seconds
unsigned long redGreenDuration = 5000; // Initial duration
bool pedestrianRequest = false;

void setup() {
  // Initialize pins
  pinMode(greenLED, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(redLED, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(pedestrianButton, INPUT_PULLUP);
  attachInterrupt(digitalPinToInterrupt(pedestrianButton), pedestrianInterrupt, FALLING);
}

void loop() {
  updateTiming(); // Read potentiometer/LDR and update timings
  manageTrafficLights(); // Manage traffic light states
}

void manageTrafficLights() {
  unsigned long currentTime = millis();

  if (pedestrianRequest==true) {
    // Pedestrian request prioritized
    digitalWrite(greenLED, HIGH);
    digitalWrite(redLED, LOW);
    
    pedestrianRequest = false;
  }
  
  // Determine the state based on the timing
  
  if ( (currentTime-lastStateChangeTime) >= (2 * redGreenDuration) ) {
    lastStateChangeTime = currentTime; // Reset cycle
  }
  else {
    if ( (currentTime-lastStateChangeTime) < redGreenDuration ) {
      digitalWrite(greenLED, LOW);
      digitalWrite(redLED, HIGH); // Red state
    } else if ( (currentTime-lastStateChangeTime) < (2*redGreenDuration-greenFlashingDuration) ) {
      digitalWrite(redLED, LOW);
      digitalWrite(greenLED, HIGH); // Green state
    } else {
      digitalWrite(redLED, LOW);
      
      if ( ( (currentTime-lastStateChangeTime) >= (2*redGreenDuration-greenFlashingDuration) ) 
      && ( (currentTime-lastStateChangeTime) % (greenFlashingDuration/3) < (greenFlashingDuration/6) ) ){
        digitalWrite(greenLED, LOW);
      } else {
        digitalWrite(greenLED, HIGH);
      }
      
    }
  }
  
}

void updateTiming() {
  // Read potentiometer/LDR values and map to timings
  // Update redGreenDuration and greenFlashingDuration accordingly
  redGreenDuration = map(analogRead(potentiometer), 0, 1023, 5000, 10000);
}

void pedestrianInterrupt() {
  pedestrianRequest = true;
  // Quickly change to green if in red state
  if (digitalRead(redLED) == HIGH) {
    digitalWrite(greenLED, HIGH);
    digitalWrite(redLED, LOW);
    lastStateChangeTime = millis(); // Reset the cycle
  }
  
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is some simplified example code that might be useful to you.

It keeps the logic and the LED control separated by the use of flags.

Simulation is at https://wokwi.com/projects/389132610627050497

```cpp
// https://arduino.stackexchange.com/questions/95476/fixing-a-pedestrian-traffic-light-sequence-pattern-in-a-cycle-using-millis-and-w

// for simulation, see https://wokwi.com/projects/389127817478781953

const int redLED   = 2;
const int greenLED = 3;

unsigned int timeInterval  [4] = {  5,  3,  4,  0};             // timers reload with these values
unsigned int timeCounter   [4] = {  0,  0,  0,  0};             // these are the actual timers

//boolean    reloadable    [4] = {true, true, false, false};    // this determines if the timer will restart upon reaching end
                                                                // put value in <timeCounter> for oneshot event 
                                                                // 3rd and 4th timers are not used in this example sketch

boolean       tick [4]  = {false, false, false, false};         // countdown timers flags
boolean       mainTick  = false;
boolean       subTick   = false;

boolean       red       = false;
boolean       green     = false;
boolean       blink     = false;


unsigned long previousMillis = 0;

void setup() {

  Serial.begin(115200);

//memcpy(timeCounter, timeInterval, 4 * sizeof(long));           // preload timers

  green = true;                                                  // start with green
  timeCounter[0] = 1;                                            // load the first counter

}

void loop() {

  unsigned long currentMillis = millis();

// -------------------------------------------------------------------

  if (currentMillis - previousMillis >= 500) {                    // 0.5 s tick
    previousMillis = currentMillis;
    subTick = !subTick;                                           // alternate the value

    if (subTick) {
      mainTick = true;                                            // 1 s tick

  //  Serial.println("tick");                                     // debugging code

      for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {                               // keep track of 4 time intervals

        timeCounter[i]-- ;                                        // decrement counter

        if (timeCounter[i] == 0) {
  //      if (reloadable[i])  timeCounter[i] = timeInterval[i];   // reached zero, reload counter if it is reloadable
          tick[i] = true;                                         // emit a "tick"
        }
      }
    }
  }

// -------------------------------------------------------------------

  if (mainTick) {                                         // 1 s tick
  }

// -------------------------------------------------------------------

  if (tick[0]) {                                          //
    tick[0] = false;
    timeCounter[1] = timeInterval[1];                     // setup the next tick

    red   = false;                                        // setup flags
    green = true;
    blink = false;
  }

// -------------------------------------------------------------------

  if (tick[1]) {                                          //
    tick[1] = false;                                      // clear flag so that code runs only once every tick
    timeCounter[2] = timeInterval[2];                     // setup the next tick

    red   = true;
    green = false;
    blink = false;
  }

// -------------------------------------------------------------------

  if (tick[2]) {                                          //
    tick[2] = false;                                      // clear flag so that code runs only once every tick
    timeCounter[0] = timeInterval[0];                     // setup the next tick

    red   = false;
    green = false;
    blink = true;
  }

// -------------------------------------------------------------------

  if (mainTick) {                                         // can have multiples of these
    mainTick = false;                                     // clear the flag in the last one
  }

// -------------------------------------------------------------------

  digitalWrite(redLED  , red             ? HIGH:LOW);     // C++ ternary operator
  digitalWrite(greenLED, green           ? HIGH:LOW);
  digitalWrite(redLED  , blink && subTick? HIGH:LOW);     // subTick changes every 500 ms
}
```

Comment: Your Wokwi link is broken.

Comment: @RussellMcMahon I tested the link on multiple devices, none of which were logged into Wokwi ... they all worked ... are you able to reach https://wokwi.com/ ?

Comment: It works for me now. I was able to access Wokwi. I tried accessing it only a few minutes after you posted the link. Mayhaps there was some setup time. || They need an NRF24L01 peripheral, or better still, a mesh of them :-). (That would be useful to me at present).

Comment: @RussellMcMahon they have a "custom chip" available ... it can be programmed with C++, Rust and Verilog ... perhaps it could be made to emulate an NRF24L01